# How to get information about a list item by id?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have an application in which, when clicking on FAB, a new list item appears with title description and id. I need that when clicking on an item, a bottom modal dialog up in which you can edit the title and description of this item. In the application I use Provider. How to make the modal window take information about this item by event id through the Provider when clicking on the modal and display?

```js
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Consumer<ListModel>(
          builder: (context, event, child) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: event.eventList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    key: Key(event.eventList[index].id),
                    title: Text(
                      event.eventList[index].title),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          event.eventList[index].detail),
                        Text(
                          event.eventList[index].id),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return ModalBottomSheet();
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Provider.of<ListModel>(context, listen: false).addEventToList();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class ModalBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const ModalBottomSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ModalBottomSheet> createState() => _ModalBottomSheetState();
}

class _ModalBottomSheetState extends State<ModalBottomSheet> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('Change Event'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "taking"? Getting Data of `eventList`?

Comment: Yes, I need to get its information when clicking on an item

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make your `ModalBottomShee` except an int (which is the id) in its constructor.

Then you can simply pass the `index` variable you get from the `Consumer`'s builder to it.

Once you have the id there, you can reach the corresponding event in the list using Provider and the List.where() method, and read or modify it.

See example changes in the code bellow.

```js
class ModalBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final int eventId;
  const ModalBottomSheet({required this.eventId,  Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ModalBottomSheet> createState() => _ModalBottomSheetState();
}

class _ModalBottomSheetState extends State<ModalBottomSheet> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('Change Event which id is ${widget.id}'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Consumer<ListModel>(
          builder: (context, event, child) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: event.eventList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    key: Key(event.eventList[index].id),
                    title: Text(
                      event.eventList[index].title),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          event.eventList[index].detail),
                        Text(
                          event.eventList[index].id),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return ModalBottomSheet(event.eventList[index].id);
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Provider.of<ListModel>(context, listen: false).addEventToList();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to search(where()) by id in my ChangeNotifier?

Comment: yes if you're passing an id you search by id.

I edited my answer 
it was `ModalBottomSheet(index);` I made it `ModalBottomSheet(event.eventList[index].id);`  to be more accurate.